# C crashes while finishing closed function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, crash, parameter-passing

I currently have a basic C program that generates and saves values to an array inside a struct. The program crashes whenever it calls a basic function. Does anyone know what is wrong with this?

```
#define SAMPLES 10   

struct values {
    double values[SAMPLES],mean;  } values;

int main()
{
    struct values array[0];
    setvals(array);
    return 0;
}

void setvals(struct values array[0]){
     int i;
     for( i = 0 ; i < SAMPLES ; i++ ) {
          array[0].values[i] = 2;
          printf("struct val = %f\n",array[0].values[i]);
      }
      printf("exitingfunc");
}
```

I can see the values in the struct being set to 2 however as soon as "exitingfunc" is printed the whole program crashes - I get no errors or warning on compiling. Any ideas why this happens?

Any and all help appriciated,

Thanks, J

Comment: Try declaring the array with a size greater than 0.

Comment: The array has zero elements. So writing to any element is outside the array bounds.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB it's been edited.  OP, some ways to improve the question: what error did you get exactly?  Try phrasing it as an actual question (e.g. "Why am I getting a segfault in this simple example I created to demonstrate the effect?").  Tell us what you tried (for example, have you heard of GDB or MSVC?).

Comment: @imallett: [I don't know what you're referring to.](http://ideone.com/fypVjT)

Comment: @KerrekSB it was edited to reduce even more glaring errors.  I'm not surprised it still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-heap array of size 0 isn't legal Standard C.

(Are you looking at your compiler error/warning output? Some compilers will allow it, and may or may not complain.)

An allocation on the heap can take a zero and returns a pointer value you can safely free. It might be NULL or a valid memory address (which you are not allowed to access).

Although here you are actually trying to use the non-existent first (ie indexed by 0) element of the array. So declare it to have one element instead.

```
struct values array[1];
```

Of course, it is strange that you are declaring a one-element array. Maybe you are intending to use a larger number later. But if all you want is to be able to change a variable of type values then you should learn how to pass pointers to (ie addresses of) variables to change them in functions:

```
struct values a;
...
setvals(&a);
...
void setvals(struct values *a){ /* or struct values a[] or a[1] */
    ...
    (*a).values[i] = 2; /* or pa->values[i] */
```

Note also that when you declare a parameter using array notation it still only defines a pointer.

Comment: There's always a simpler solution than a one-element array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following definition:

```
struct values array[0];
```

It will allocate an array with zero elements—that is, no memory at all.  By writing to it inside `setvals`, you will overwrite the heap structure containing the return address to `main`.  Consequently, when trying to jump to the address 0x00000002, a segmentation fault is thrown.  Change the definition to

```
struct values array[1];
```

and the program will work (although you might want to change the argument list to `setvals`, as well).

Note also that

- you defined a global struct called `values` which you didn't actually use,
- instead of passing a one-element array to `setvals`, you could just pass a pointer,
- you should preferably use an unsigned integer for `i`,
- `2` is actually an integer literal, not a double literal (which would be `2.`), and
- the printed string `"exitingfunc"` isn't terminated by a newline.

All things considered, your program might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SAMPLES 10

struct values {
    double values[SAMPLES], mean;
};

void setvals(struct values *array)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++) {
        array->values[i] = 2.;
        printf("struct val = %f\n", array->values[i]);
    }
    printf("exitingfunc\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct values array;
    setvals(&array);
    return 0;
}
```

---

There is a valuable tool for examining this kind of errors: the memory error detector `memcheck`, part of the tool suite (and invoked by the command) `valgrind`.  Here is what it outputs for your program:

```
==6180== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6180== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6180== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6180== Command: ./a.out
==6180==
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
struct val = 2.000000
==6180== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==6180==    at 0x4000000000000000: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==  Address 0x4000000000000000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6180==
==6180==
==6180== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6180==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x4000000000000000
==6180==    at 0x4000000000000000: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
==6180==    by 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
exitingfunc==6180==
==6180== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6180==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6180==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==6180==
==6180== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6180==
==6180== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6180== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

The crucial message here is

```
Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
```

It tells you that you either played around with function pointers and it turned out bad (which you didn't), or the stack has been corrupted.  This, in turn, points you to the bogus local array definition.